# Telerik MVC Extensions documentation

Tags: telerik-mvc

I've been working with Telerik MVC Extensions since around 2012 and have used this product across a host of projects and different jobs.  Recently, I noticed that the documentation for the project vanished.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a place where you can find the documentation for either download or viewing.  It would be extremely helpful.

As is, there are simple things that I can't remember and always referenced the documentation for (such as how to select a node within a Tree View).